# Find a function that makes two regions of a rectangle have a certain proportion

Tags: calculus, area

The problem states the following: A curve $y-f(x)=0$ passes through the origin, and $R_{x}$ is the rectangle formed by the coordinate axis and the parallel lines that pass through the point $(x,f(x))$ of the curve. If the curve divides the rectangle in two regions and the area of one of them is 10 times the area of the other one,  find $f(x)$.

Excuse my awful figure but graphically I think of it this way: [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzKMZ.png). The blue part is $\int_0^a f(x)dx$ and the purple part is 10 times the blue part, meaning $10 \int_0^a f(x)dx$. Since the total area is $ab$, the blue part + the purple part $= 11\int_0^a f(x)dx= ab$. I don't know how to proceed from here so any kind of help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are supposed to have $b=f(a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

We look for $f (x) $ such that

$$(1+10)\int_0^xf (t)dt=xf (x) $$

(sum of two areas $=$area of the rectangle).

differentiating  gives

$$11f (x)=f (x)+xf'(x) $$

You can finish and get

> $$f (x)=\lambda x^{10} $$

The other solution satisfies
$$(1+\frac {1}{10})\int_0^xf (t)dt=xf (x) $$

gives

> $$f (x)=\mu x^\frac {1}{10} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{x}f(t) = 10\left[xf(x) - \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\right]$

$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)= \frac{10}{11}\left[xf(x)\right]$

Differentiating

$f(x) = \frac{10}{11}\left[xf'(x)+f(x)\right]$

$\frac{1}{11}f(x) = \frac{10}{11}xf'(x)$

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{10x}$

$ln(f(x)) = \frac{1}{10}lnx +lnc$

$f(x) = cx^{\frac{1}{10}}$